# Delete entries if more than 50

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

For example I can have 75 entries for same computer, in this case: `clt98079`

and I want to delete the last entries if it exceeds 50 (the oldest ones, by date) and keep the newest 50 entries. How can I finish my transaction? I am checking by column for pc `Hostname` and by old entries with column `CheckDate`

```
begin tran
    if  (Select Count(*) FROM dbo.Clients WHERE Hostname='clt98079') > 50
    begin
        delete from dbo.Clients where ID in (
            select dbo.Clients.CheckDate from dbo.Clients
            /////not sure how to finish the last bit here/////
        )
    end
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server, which gives you the option of an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by hostname order by checkdate desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.Clients c
      where hostname = 'clt98079'
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 50;
```

Note that you can remove the `where` clause to keep the most recent 50 for all hostnames.

Comment: Thank You very much for the fast answer and worked perfectly! To understand it better, basically this code here selects all entries where it matches the hostname and then automatically, if I see correctly, it deletes whatever is exceeded over the mentioned number, correct?